# Camera code works in android version below API level 14

Tags: android, android-camera

My sample camera code which works in android API levels below 14

When I tried in API level 14 or above, it throws null pointer exception.
please can you tell me where I am going wrong.

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    cam= Camera.open();
    Log.e("msg", cam+"");
    mp=new MyPreview(getApplicationContext(), cam);
    frame1.addView(mp);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera open", 5).show();
}
```

**Mypreview** is a class which extends SurfaceView and implements SurfaceHolder.CallBack

code is:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class MyPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private Camera _cam;
private SurfaceHolder sh;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public MyPreview(Context context, Camera _cam) {
    super(context);
    this._cam = _cam;
    sh=getHolder();
    sh.addCallback(this);
    sh.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Camera.Parameters cp = _cam.getParameters();
    cp.setPreviewSize(width, height);

    cp.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);


    _cam.setParameters(cp);
    _cam.setDisplayOrientation(90);

    _cam.startPreview();

}



@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        _cam.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    _cam.stopPreview();
}

}
```

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash. If you do not understand the stack trace, paste it here, and point out what lines in your code correspond to lines in the stack trace.

Comment: On which is it throwing null pointer exception ?
Check the minimum sdk api level in manifest